# Default value not being applied on Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have this migration:

```
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->char('sku', 13)->primary();
        $table->enum('status', ['disabled', 'enabled', 'suspended', 'locked', 'hidden'])->default('disabled');
        $table->char('category')->nullable();
        $table->char('group')->nullable();
        $table->char('name');
        $table->char('description')->nullable();
        $table->char('brand')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('cost', 8, 4)->default('0');
        $table->decimal('price', 8, 4)->default('0');
        $table->decimal('existences', 8, 4)->default('0');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('contact_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts');
        $table->integer('sat_code')->nullable();
        $table->char('sat_unit')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('order')->default('99999');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My update method in the controller is this:

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    // TODO: permitir el cambio de ID
    $product->fill($request->all());
    $product->save();

    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'ok',
        'msg' => 'SKU modificado con exito',
    ], 200);
}
```

And the fields on the view are this:

```
                    <div class="form-group col-4">
                        <label for="">Costo:</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" form="modal-form" placeholder="0.0">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-4">
                        <label for="">Precio:</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" form="modal-form" placeholder="0.0">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
        $.post(url, $('#modal-form').serialize())
            .done(function(data) {
                if (data.success === 'ok') {
                    $('#modal-create').hide();
                    location.reload();
                } else if (data.success === 'error') {
                    toastr.error(data.msg);
                }
            })
```

But if i leave the COST field emtpy i got an error saying:

Column 'cost' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `products` (`name`, `description`, `brand`, `cost`, `price`, `sat_code`, `sat_unit`, `sku`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (asdsad, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ASDADASDA, 2021-03-11 20:45:59, 2021-03-11 20:45:59))"

What can I be doing wrong? isnt the default value on the migration should me applying if the cost field is empty or null?

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: You are passing a `null` value for that property. If you want the DB to take care of the default value, you shouldn't pass that property when you fill the model properties

Answer (score 0):

on your `$request->all()` contains `cost = null`, you need filter it, an example using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$product->fill(array_filter($request->all()));
```

Comment: Not working... but your answer give me a hint and i used a mutator instead: $this->attributes['cost'] = (empty($value)) ? 0 : $value;

Answer (score 0):

You can add, default value 0 and min 0 in the form number field.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" form="modal-form" placeholder="0.0" min='0' value='0' required>
```

OR

you can write

```
$formData = $request->all();
$formData['cost'] = $formData['cost'] ?? 0; // Null Coalescing Operator
$product->fill($formData);
$product->save();
```

Comment: I'll stick to the mutator (its more generic and easier to debug), but also add the default value and the min value just to be safe, thanks!!!